# racket slideshow: how to display in a window (and not fullscreen)?

Tags: racket, slideshow, windowed

When I run slideshow, it automatically run in full screen. I searched in the options but I can't find anything to display slideshow in a window.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-s` flag at the command-line.

E.G.

```
% slideshow -s 300 300 my-slideshow.rkt
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's a bit rudimentary. I don't have maximize or minimize buttons, I can't move the window, ...

Comment: Right, that's correct. Not resizable, no maximize or minimize buttons. Still, I think that's what's available. For more information, consider posting to the racket discourse group, at racket.discourse.group . There's also a discord instance.